# OpenCV estimateAffine3D in Python: shapes of input matrix?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to find a transformation matrix that relates 2 3D point clouds. According to the documentation, cv2.estimateAffine3D(src, dst) --> retval, out, inliers.

src is the first 3D point set, dst is the second 3D point set.
I'm assuming that retval is a boolean.
Out is the 3x4 affine transformation matrix, and inliers is a vector.

My question is, what are the shapes of the input point sets? Do the points have to be homogeneous, i.e. 4xN?

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand from source code, they have to be Point3D, i.e. non-homogenous.